# Vmware powercli on win2008r2 get-stat empty "string"

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli, esx

when I am getting statistics from ESXi using vmware powercli on windows7 it gives me responce
**Wondows7**
command: PowerCLI C:\temp>

```
Get-VMHost -Name "hostname.inc.com" | Get-Stat -Stat
 cpu.usage.average  -Start (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -Finish(Get-Date) -MaxSamples 100
```

returns output

```
MetricId                Timestamp                          Value Unit     Insta
                                                                          nce
--------                ---------                          ----- ----     -----
cpu.usage.average       31.10.2013 15:40:00                25,03 %
cpu.usage.average       31.10.2013 15:35:00                22,95 %
cpu.usage.average       31.10.2013 15:30:00                23,97 %
...
```

when from 
**Windows2008r2**
command: PowerCLI C:\temp>

```
Get-VMHost -Name "hostname.inc.com" | Get-Stat -Stat
 cpu.usage.average  -Start (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -Finish(Get-Date) -MaxSamples 100
```

returns "nothing"

Interesting- if run on windows2008r2 
command: PowerCLI C:\temp>

```
Get-VMHost -Name "hostname.inc.com" | Get-Stat -Stat
 cpu.usage.average  -Realtime -MaxSamples 100
```

it gives responce

```
cpu.usage.average       10/31/2013 9:49:40 AM               9.77 %        30
cpu.usage.average       10/31/2013 9:49:20 AM               8.63 %        30
cpu.usage.average       10/31/2013 9:49:00 AM              12.05 %        30
cpu.usage.average       10/31/2013 9:48:40 AM               11.5 %        30
cpu.usage.average       10/31/2013 9:48:20 AM              14.25 %        30
cpu.usage.average       10/31/2013 9:48:00 AM              11.02 %        30
cpu.usage.average       10/31/2013 9:47:40 AM              11.77 %        30
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your version of Powershell on the Windows 7 box is handling your syntax error to do with the lack of space in the line `-Finish(Get-Date)` (it should be `-Finish (Get-Date)`) - whereas the Powershell version on the Windows 2008 R2 box does not handle the error. So when you remove the `-Start` and `-Finish` switches, you are removing the syntax error to do with `-Finish`.

It should be:

```
Get-VMHost -Name "hostname.inc.com" | Get-Stat -Stat cpu.usage.average -Start (GetDate).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date) -MaxSamples 100
```